# Where to make an instance of the stream (or any other thing that I need) regards to the Clean Architecture (Uncle Bob)?

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

If I want to add the List of data from Database (I am using Floor database) to the stream. Where would I create that stream in regards to the Clean Architecture?

If I use stream directly with database than I am obligated to update every little change in database so that stream can rebuild my screen. In some sense I feel restricted to manipulate data directly.

Example: I want to select an item in the list and it will change color and then I would delete selected items with for loop or something which means that every time I select an item I need to update it in database so that stream knows that there was a change and it will rebuild the screen. Or if I have toggleAll usecase for selection it will be extremely slow.

I want `Future<List<Item>> getItems` not `Stream<List<Item>> getItems` in DAO file so that I can have access to the list make changes to it and return it to the stream.

The problem is where I can create the stream?

If I create it in the RepositoryImplementation class then my methods will be obligated to update the stream and the database which are 2 responsibilities and I would even need to write the logic for the stream update which doesn't make sense since usecase is responsible for the logic. And even that, shouldn't Repository only work with datasources?

I am building the NoteApp using Bloc for state management.

NoteRepositoryImpl

```
class NoteRepositoryImpl implements NoteRepository {
  final NoteLocalDataSource _noteLocalDataSource;

  NoteRepositoryImpl(this._noteLocalDataSource);

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, Stream<List<Note>>>> getNotes() async {
    try {
      final noteModelStream = _noteLocalDataSource.getNotes();
      final noteStream = noteModelStream.map((List<NoteModel> noteModels) =>
          noteModels.map((noteModel) => noteModel.toNote()).toList());
      return Right(noteStream);
    } on DatabaseException catch (error) {
      return Left(DatabaseFailure(error.message));
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, Success>> insertNote(Note note) async {
    try {
      final noteModel = NoteModel.fromNote(note);
      await _noteLocalDataSource.insertNote(noteModel);
      return const Right(Success());
    } on DatabaseException catch (error) {
      return Left(DatabaseFailure(error.message));
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, Success>> removeNote(Note note) async {
    try {
      final noteModel = NoteModel.fromNote(note);
      await _noteLocalDataSource.removeNote(noteModel);
      return const Right(Success());
    } on DatabaseException catch (error) {
      return Left(DatabaseFailure(error.message));
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, Success>> updateNote(Note note) async {
    try {
      final noteModel = NoteModel.fromNote(note);
      await _noteLocalDataSource.updateNote(noteModel);
      return const Right(Success());
    } on DatabaseException catch (error) {
      return Left(DatabaseFailure(error.message));
    }
  }
}
```